# Java unable to recognise special character after space

Tags: java, whitespace, symbols

I have to write a program for the following problem:

[image]

I have written the following code:

```
package secret_message;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Secret_Message {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        int lines, i, codenumber, k;
        String code, codepart, codechar2;
        char codecharacter1, codecharacter2;
        lines = sc.nextInt();
        codepart = "";
        for (i = 1; i<=lines; i++)
        {
            code = sc.next();
            codecharacter1 = code.charAt(0);
            codecharacter2 = code.charAt(1);
            codenumber = Character.getNumericValue(codecharacter1);
            for (k=1; k<=codenumber; k++)
            {
                codechar2 = Character.toString(codecharacter2);
                codepart = codepart + " " + codechar2;
            }
            System.out.println(codepart); 
            codepart = "";
        }
    } 
}
```

It works perfectly when my input on each line does not have a space (for example if I write "9+" instead of "9 +"). However, on writing "9 +" for example, I get the following error: "String index out of range". I tried changing `codecharacter2 = code.charAt(1);` in my code to `codecharacter2 = code.charAt(2);` and `codecharacter2 = code.charAt(3);` with no success. I also attempted to create a new variable using `code.replaceAll("\\s", "");` but this would also remove the "+" in "9 +".

I know it only makes a subtle difference to include the space but the question explicitly states the need for it. Hence, I would appreciate any help on how I can get around this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here `code = sc.next();` this means you are only taking the first token from the input which is the first character. Instead you need to take the entire line as per your logic i.e.,

```
code = sc.nextLine();
```

Better solution would be to take the integer and character separately. Check below code:

```
    for (i = 1; i<=lines; i++)
    {
        codenumber= sc.nextInt();
        codechar2 = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
        for (k=1; k<=codenumber; k++)
        {
            codepart = codepart + " " + codechar2;
        }
        System.out.println(codepart); 
        codepart = "";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I never even considered that `code = sc.next();` could be where the problem was! In fact, I also realised that my previous code would only work for numbers 0-9 while the problem allows any positive integer below 80. `codenumber= sc.nextInt();` helped fix this problem! I also changed `codecharacter2 = code.charAt(1);` to `codecharacter2 = code1.charAt((code1.length()) - 1);` which worked perfectly! After fixing a few more basic errors, the code ran smoothly :)